# OkHttp PublicKey pinning on Android

Tags: java, android, okhttp, pinning

Does anyone know how we could implement Public Key pinning with OkHttp3

Have been reading about SSL pinning and I  see that we could do it with either Certificate Pinning or Public Key pinning (the latter seems more flexible). But I was only able to find example of [Certificate pinning](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS#certificate-pinning) with OkHttp and none of Key Pinning.

Does anyone know how easy this is to implement with OkHttp (and/or an example of how to go about doing so)?

TIA

Comment: Everything is possible, the question is how complex it is. Regarding OkHttp it looks like it is more complex than necessary because some strange programmer made the class `CertificatePinner` final. Otherwise you could have used it as a base for an implementation of public key pinning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Been looking through the source of the [CertificatePinner](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/6da4d59c2047c2d1d40625cebf87604e0d22b335/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.java) in OkHttp3 and it seems that the implementation is actually a Public Key check so is in fact an implementation of Public Key Pinning (hence adding this as an answer).

Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Yup. OkHttp’s pinning works the same as HPKP and it should be all you need.

Comment: @JesseWilson Thanks for the confirmation :)